# How to know the last character entered in input - Javascript

Tags: javascript, input, keyboard-events, onkeyup

Assuming we have the following input:

```
<input id="myInput" type='text' onkeyup="validate(this.value)" />

function validate(character) {
    console.log(character)
}
```

The problem is that I only get the overall value of the input. For example, if I write 2, it returns 2 but if I write a 7 it returns 27, when it should return only 7.

Comment: character[character.length-1]

Comment: @EugeneSunic I have thought about it but the problem is what happens if I place the character in another position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just retrieve the `KeyboardEvent` property [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)  from the "keyup" event like this:

```js
//assign the input element to a variable
let input = document.querySelector("#myInput"); 

//add a keyup listener to the input that will run the function passing the event to the function as an argument
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    console.log(e.key);
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type='text'/>
```

**JSFiddle with above code:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/n18wqzjm/4/

---

**But wait, what if I want certain keys to run something else like say, run a different console.log instead?**

Well, you can just add a conditional statement that checks the key property value and compare it with individual keys like this:

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#myInput");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
 if (e.key === "Delete") {
    //if the DELETE key is pressed, don't run the default console.log but do something else
    console.log("You are trying to add delete key as a character: " + e.key);
  } else if (e.key === "Escape") {
    //if the ESCAPE key is pressed, don't run the default console.log but do something else
   console.log("You are trying to add escape key as a character: " + e.key);
  } else {
    //run the default console.log
   console.log(e.key);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type='text'/>
```

Comment: "keypress" event can also be used, it means keyDown + KeyUP

Comment: What if the last key pressed is `delete`? For validation this might not be as useful as looking at the actual value in the input.

Comment: @MarkMeyer That's a valid point and certain conditons can be added where if the key property value matches certain keyboard keys e.g. the `delete` key as you mentioned, something else will run. A simple example would be an if statement that checks if the key property value is equal to "Delete", log something else to the console. But as far as logging the last key pressed to the console is concerned, the above would be the best approach to this :)

Comment: As a matter of fact, let me add that to the answer. Thanks for bringing a valid point up.

Answer (score 0):

The one simplest solution I can think of is `console.log(character[character.length-1])`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the whole text is that you give the validate function the whole input value. To check the last input character you can split the text to the last char and examine it. 
If you want to allow certain characters to be entered you have to check each time this char.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "String"; 
var result = input.charAt(input.length-1);
```

Output: g